# Proper way to loop in directory only acting on .pcap files

Tags: bash, files

Is this legal in bash perform a nested for loop on a directory of files matching only .pcap files?

```
ROOTFILEPATH = '/a/path'
FILEEXT = '.pcap'
for file in $ROOTFILEPATH
for $FILEEXT in file; do
    #do something
done
```

Thank you.

Comment: And mind the spaces around the equal signs

Comment: are `=` with spaces not allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to nest the loop, you can tell your first loop to only act on `*.pcap` files.

```
#! /bin/bash -

for CUR_FILE in "/PATH/TO/DIR/"*.pcap; do
    echo "$CUR_FILE"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

To loop through a directory, selecting only given extensions, where both the directory and the extension are variables:

```
rootfilepath='/a/path'
fileext='.pcap'
for file in "$rootfilepath"/*"$fileext"
do
  : something with "$file"
done
```

I made several changes to your original:

- lower-cased the variable names. Just a convention; it helps to avoid several baked-in variables with all upper-case names.
- removed the spaces around the variable assignment; otherwise, the variable name itself is taken as a command to execute with two parameters: an equal-sign and the remaining variable-value.
- added a missing `do` to the loop
- used shell globbing (`*`) between the directory and the file extension to pick up all the files in that path with that extension